# Obtener los archivos de vue2-dropzone

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dropzone, dropzone.js

Estoy tratando de obtener los archivos de `vue2-dropzone` para subir los archivos cuando envio los datos del formulario, intente con:

```
this.$refs.dropzone_test.files
```

y con

```
this.$refs.dropzone_test.dropzone.files
```

pero en ninguno de los casos pude obtener los archivos.

Hay alguna manera de obtener los archivos de dropzone para adjuntarlos al formulario en Vue.Js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu componente de `dropzone` tienes que escuchar a los siguientes eventos:

- `vdropzone-sending(file, xhr, formData)` : Modifique la solicitud y agregue parámetros adicionales para solicitar antes de enviarla.
- `vdropzone-success(file, response)`: El archivo se ha cargado correctamente. Obtiene la respuesta del servidor como segundo argumento.
- `vdropzone-removed-file(file, error, xhr)`:  Se eliminó un archivo de la zona de colocación.
- `vdropzone-queue-complete()`: Se activa cuando la cola se ha procesado / cargado por completo.

Puedes averiguar los eventos del `dropzone` y mas, entra aqui [aqui](https://rowanwins.github.io/vue-dropzone/docs/dist/#/events)

**HTML**

```
<dropzone :headers="headers"
           id="upload-file"
           @vdropzone-sending="sendingEvent"
           @vdropzone-success="uploadDropzoneFinish"
           @vdropzone-removed-file="removeFileDropzone"
           @vdropzone-queue-complete="uploadFinish"
           :maxFileSizeInMB="8"
           :useFontAwesome="true"
           :options="dropzoneOptions"
           :language="langDropzone">
   <div class="dropzone-custom-content">
     <h1>¡Arrastra y suelta para subir fotos y videos! o haga clic para seleccionar un archivo de su computadora</h1>
   </div>
</dropzone>
```

Lo que tu necesitas es declaras una variable donde guardar estos elementos y una funcion donde captures estos elementos y lo guardes en la variable ya creada.
Para esto usare el evento `vdropzone-success` de la siguiente manera.

**VueJS + Typescript**

```
public uploadedFiles: any[] = [];

uploadDropzoneFinish(file) {
  this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me ayudo muchisimo, Saludos !!

Comment: De nada, amigo :D